# Join statement with different conditions on different row set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I need join two tables using different conditions on different row sets.

For example if `RowID < 100 on t1.ColA = t2.ColB` and if `RowID >= 100 on t1.ColA = t2.ColB+1`

I implemented this as below:

```
... On (RowID <100 and t1.ColA=t2.ColB) OR (RowID >=100 on t1.ColA=t2.ColB+1) ...
```

But it's very very slow, so what is the problem and what is the better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RowID <100 on t1.ColA=t2.ColB 

UNION ALL

If RowID >=100 on t1.ColA=t2.ColB+1
```

Try This solution.

Comment: +1 As the OR statement prolly breaks his Index this solution should add it fast.

Comment: Very good. 1s for 200000 records, But what is my query problem?!

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
On t1.ColA=CASE
WHEN RowID<100 THEN t2.ColB
WHEN RowID>=100 THEN t2.ColB+1
END
```

or

```
SELECT
...
CASE
    WHEN RowID<100 THEN t2.Column
    WHEN RowID>=100 THEN t3.Column
END
...
Join t2 On t1.ColA=t2.ColB
Join t2 as t3 On t1.ColA=t3.ColB+1
```

may be it will be faster

Comment: ok, how about two separate equi joins instead of one non equi join? Did you try this?