# bad query optimizer strategy with subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

I have a query that takes very long because of an uncessary full scan of a very big table.

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT count(*)
FROM BigTable
WHERE (username = 'me' OR id IN (SELECT id FROM SmallTable WHERE username = 'me'));
```

`BigTable` has an index for both columns `username` and `id`. So I assumed this query would be very fast, but actually it takes a lot of time because mysql queries all 4 million rows of *BigTable*.

Explain returns:

> 1, PRIMARY, BigTable, index, BigTable_N52, BigTable_N52, 9, NULL,  4364507, "Using where; Using index"
>
> 2, SUBQUERY, SmallTable, ref, "...", SmallTable_username, 9, const, 11, NULL

Surprisingly when I remove the subquery and add actual ids performance and query planner strategy is as expected:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT count(*)
FROM BigTable
WHERE (username = 'me' OR id IN (1,2,3,4));
```

Explain:

> 1, SIMPLE, BigTable, index_merge, "PRIMARY, BigTable_N52", "BigTable_N52,PRIMARY", "9,8", NULL, 236, "Using union(BigTable_N52,PRIMARY); Using where"

Any ideas on how I can fix it?

Comment: Have you tried replacing your sub query with a view?

[http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51264/how-to-get-performance-benefits-from-a-view-vs-subquery][1]


  [1]: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51264/how-to-get-performance-benefits-from-a-view-vs-subquery

Comment: You mention there are indices for `BigTable.username` and `BigTable.id`, but what about `SmallTable.username`? If not, creating an index for that would speed up the subquery.

Comment: @Mark good point, but `SmallTable.username` has already an index

Comment: @linqu Did you give something like `SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM
  (SELECT
     id
   FROM BigTable
   WHERE username = 'me'
   UNION
   SELECT SmallTable.id
   FROM BigTable
   JOIN SmallTable
     ON BigTable.id = SmallTable.id
   WHERE SmallTable.username = 'me'
   ) T
;` a try?

Comment: Yes that's what I went with finally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(c_rec) FROM
(
SELECT count(*) AS c_rec
FROM BigTable
WHERE (username = 'me')
UNION ALL
SELECT count(*)
FROM BigTable
WHERE id
IN (SELECT id FROM SmallTable WHERE username = 'me')
) t
```

Try This Solution.

Comment: also <IN> can be converted may be converted to <INNER JOIN> with SmallTable

Comment: What happens if a row has username = me and id = 1 ? I think it will be counted twice with this solution.

Comment: OR clause usually difficult to database optimizator

Comment: @realnumber3012 do you imply that MySQL can't efficiently solve the query at once and you need a UNION to split it up into two queries?
And, why the downvote?

Comment: for example(SQL SERVER): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352310/join-statement-with-different-conditions-on-different-row-set/18352376#18352376

Comment: thanks realnumber3012 for your answer, I indeed have the problem of double counted rows as @Horia pointed out, but apparently there is no other soltuion. I can overcome this problem by a count(distinct id) in the wrapping select.

Comment: @linqu For `COUNT(DISTINCT id)` in the outer query, you'd need to change the `UNION ALL`ed `SELECT`s to go after the ids (rather than their counts) anyway. Once there, you might want to test the effect of switching to just `UNION` (with the effect of then no longer needing the `DISTINCT`).

Answer (score 1):

The construct `IN ( SELECT ... )` optimizes very poorly.  Turn it into a `JOIN`.

Doing this `JOIN` in addition to @realnumber3012's `UNION` will make it even faster.

As for the inflation-of-COUNT-due-to-JOIN, give this a try:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM
    (
      ( SELECT  id
            FROM  BigTable
            WHERE  username = 'me'
      ) UNION  DISTINCT 
      ( SELECT  id
            FROM  BigTable b
            JOIN  SmallTable s USING(id)
            WHERE  s.username = 'me')
      )
    ) t
```

If finds the ids in two ways, then DISTINCTifies them before COUNTing them.